# This is a question of ethics

Tags: materialism, eastern-philosophy, reductionism, moral-realism

Few thousand years ago two Indian schools carvakas and Ajivikas challenged Karma doctrine , as there was no good or bad deeds and no reward or punishment , Is there any Western thought similar to this ?

Comment: perhaps if you explained what that challenge was about to people who dont know about it, they would be able to help you

Comment: The challenge is I want to know is there any other Western thinker who thought that good and bad deeds do not exist or does not bring any reward or punishment?

Comment: many people dispute the meaning of "good" and "bad" but I'm not aware of any who would say these do not exist. Rewards and punishment can come from some deity, any atheist philosopher would dispute that. But rewards and punishment can come from fellow humans, I don't know who would deny that

Comment: I am speaking from the point of Karma theory , and can you suggest some philosophers, but after all thanks.

Comment: Westerners don't believe in karma. In that aspect they all challenge the karma doctrine. Just like Asian people don't believe jesus is the son of god, so they all challenge christianity. 
However both christianity and karma imply good and bad, some retribution, and even some type of reincarnation (paradise....), the details are different though

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. A non-assertion of karma was an outcome of the charvaka philosophy as they were materialists. The Greek atomists were similar materialists. You can read about the charvakas here, under the section titled 'Materialism' - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey/mode/2up

Comment: Yes thank you I have read that , Greek materialist also might thought the same way.

Comment: Yes, Spinoza explained that what humans think of as 'good' or 'bad' depend entirely on a value judgement. In 'Ethics' III, 9S, "We neither strive for, wish, seek, or desire anything because we think it good, but on the contrary, we adjudge a thing to be good because we strive for, wish, seek, or desire it." S. Paul Kaspap explains, "What he means is that man's desires, which find an expression in an inclination and disinclination towards various things, plays a decisive role in his recognition... of things as good or bad." ("Spinoza and Moral Freedom") CMS

Comment: Would nihilism count?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihilism
Me: "I don't believe in nihilism."
Nihilist: "Great! You're in the club!"

Comment: Yes that is great

Comment: S.Paul kaspap who is that guy?